# Optimize the sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE employees
   SET job_id = (SELECT job_id
                   FROM employees
                  WHERE employee_id = 205),
       salary = (SELECT salary
                   FROM employees
                  WHERE employee_id = 205)
 WHERE employee_id = 114;
```

This is the query i have been using. Here i use 2 subqueries but they have the same where condition.. The seek time is doubled.. Is there a way to optimize the whole query to a single subquery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you post code, including SQL or XML, **please** highlight those lines in question and use the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format those!! Makes it just soooo much easier to read and understand!

Comment: @joseph does it (this syntax) work in oracle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476206/optimize-the-sql-query/2476423#2476423

Answer (score 5):

you can remove a subquery if you update a set of columns:

```
UPDATE employees
   SET (job_id, salary) 
        = (SELECT job_id, salary FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 205)
 WHERE employee_id = 114;
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't know you could do SET (job_id, salary)  = SELECT (Job_id, Salary). 

Thank you.

Comment: @Vincent, Is that syntax applicable for SQL server as well?